# How to copy one sheet 1 colums to another sheet 2

Tags: excel

I have two sheets Sheet1 and Sheet2. From Sheet2 there are two columns one with the stock name (B) and the other with Grade (F). In sheet1 I would like to match the Grade with the stock names from sheet2.

There are few that will not match anything in Sheet1 just leave blank.

Here is a pick of Sheet1 & 2 with Sheet1 column (B) to be filled in.

Sheet1 & Sheet2

[image]

Sheet3 Results into Column B

[image]

Thnx in advance for all your help.
Marty

Comment: Are you sure that they should match? I can't see Aaron's inc for example on sheet 2

Comment: Use `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:Sheet1!,match(Sheet1!C8,Sheet1!B:B,0)),"")` in cell B8 and pull down.

Comment: Sheet1 and Sheet2 do not match at all two different data bases. The result sheet will have Sheet2 Column info placed with matching ticker symbols to result Column C.

Comment: I get an error on the "match"

Comment: Figure it out. in Sheet1 Column B8 =VLOOKUP(C8,Sheet2!B2:C690,2,0)